# FQDN does not get set in Azure VM

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

#### Terraform Version

```
Terraform v0.11.10
+ provider.azurerm v1.19.0
```

#### Terraform Configuration Files

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "main" {
  name                  = "${var.prefix}-vm"
  location              = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.location}"
  resource_group_name   = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  network_interface_ids = ["${azurerm_network_interface.main.id}"]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  storage_os_disk {
    name              = "myosdisk1"
    caching           = "ReadWrite"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "head01.test.local"
    admin_username = "${var.admin_username}"
    custom_data    = "${file("custom_data.txt")}"
  }
  os_profile_linux_config {
    disable_password_authentication = true
    ssh_keys {
      path     = "/home/${var.admin_username}/.ssh/authorized_keys"
      key_data = "${var.ssh_key_data}"
    } 
  }
  tags {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}
```

#### Custom Data File

```
#cloud-config
fqdn: head01.test.local
```

#### Expected Behavior

It should set FQDN and running `hostname -f` should return full FQDN

#### Actual Behavior

`hostname` returns only first part of FQDN `head01`. 
`hostname --fqdn` fails with error `hostname: Temporary failure in name resolution`

### Additional Information

I've tried `custom_data` approach too (it is commented now). It gives the same result.

**`/etc/hosts` content**

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts

::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

**`/etc/resolv.conf` content**

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 10.4.0.5
search reddog.microsoft.com
```

Comment: What does `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf` look like?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR added them in question. Thanks

Comment: Derp, meant `/etc/nsswitch.conf` rather than `/etc/resolv.conf` but I think those 2 show your issue already.  The output of `hostnamectl` and `/etc/hostname` might also be useful to show the issue.